# How to use a 404 page to process a URL with a .md suffix？

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

My project was built using the nuxt framework.

Recently, I found a problem. When the url address of the access contains special suffixes such as .md or .txt, nuxt can't be processed correctly. Instead, it does not match nuxt router when doing normal static resource processing. When no file is found, the 404 error page that comes with the browser is thrown directly, instead of using my custom error page. When I type in .html or without a suffix, the request can be processed normally. I checked it for a long time with google, but I didn't find out what the problem was and how to deal with it.

[image: suffix with .md]

[image: suffix with .html]